# Why does React skip over the last question that is correctly set to state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I wrote a small webapp for risk scoring (asking five questions, if checkbox is checked, add points). Unfortunately after many hours of debugging I still have the same bug: It would not include the last question in the results page.

I tried to show the results `getFinalResults()` at a later time, but this results in "undefined" error when trying to set the question since there are no more questions to show.

Expected Results: *Checking all checkboxes and clicking on next from Questions A, B, C, D, E would show A, B, C, D, E on results*.

Actual Results: *Checking all checkboxes shows the following result: A, B, C, D . (Missing E)*

---

Edit: The final solution was to use a callback in setState as Linschlager suggested:

```
    setNextQuestion() {
        if (this.state.boxStateValue === true) {
            this.setState((state, props) => ({
                    resultCache: {
                        ...state.resultCache,
                        [this.state.question]: questionData[this.state.counter].points
                    }
                }), () => {
                    if (this.state.questionId === questionData.length) {
                        this.getFinalResults();
                    } else {
                        this.setState({
                            questionId: this.state.questionId +1 ,
                            counter: this.state.counter +1,
                            question: questionData[this.state.counter + 1].question,
                            boxStateValue: false
                        });
                    }
                });
        }
    }
```

Comment: One thing: App.js:44 should be `for (let e of resultPoints) {` instead of in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not actually putting the result of the last question into the `resultCache`.

`setNextQuestion` goes straight to the results for the last question

```
setNextQuestion() {
    if (this.state.questionId === questionData.length) { // If last question
        this.getFinalResults(); // goto result
    } else { // if not last question
        if (this.state.boxStateValue === true) {  // add to resultcache
            this.setState((state, props) => ({
                resultCache: {
                    ...state.resultCache,
                    [this.state.question]: questionData[this.state.questionId].points
                }
            }));
        }
        this.setState({ // go to next question
            questionId: this.state.questionId +1 ,
            counter: this.state.counter +1,
            question: questionData[this.state.counter + 1].question,
            boxStateValue: false
        });
    }
}
```

it should be more something like this:

```
setNextQuestion() {
  if (this.state.boxStateValue === true) {  // add to resultcache
    this.setState((state, props) => ({
      resultCache: {
        ...state.resultCache,
        [this.state.question]: questionData[this.state.questionId].points
      }
    }));
  }
  if (this.state.questionId === questionData.length) { // If last question
    this.getFinalResults(); // goto result
  } else {
    // go to next question
    this.setState({ // go to next question
      questionId: this.state.questionId +1 ,
      counter: this.state.counter +1,
      question: questionData[this.state.counter + 1].question,
      boxStateValue: false
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: I was going to post the exact same thing, this is likely the answer you are after @MikeyDet

Comment: Thank you both, you are right and I corrected the order. Unfortunately it has still the last result "E" missing in the resultcache before it tries to call this.getFinalResults();. It seems it is due to the async nature to state. I will try to refactor it using a result object instead of state.

Comment: or you could use the callback in `setState(updater[, callback])` to enforce the order.
https://itnext.io/react-setstate-usage-and-gotchas-ac10b4e03d60

Comment: Thanks @Linschlager, the callback brought the solution as you suggested.